# CheckboxList Display All Selected Boxes

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkboxlist

I submit the form and receive an email that states the results of the form, in this case it will be if any of the three checkboxes have been selected. My current issue is that it won't display that the second or third checkbox is selected if more then one checkbox is selected.

Example: I check all three checkboxes my result is:

- Marketing Mailings: Yes
- 3rd Party Mailings: No
- VISA Promotions: No

When should display as all of them saying Yes like this:

- Marketing Mailings: Yes
- 3rd Party Mailings: Yes
- VISA Promotions: Yes

My front page code:

```
<td class="nobor">
        <asp:CheckBoxList ID="OptList" runat="server">
        </asp:CheckBoxList>
```

My Page Load:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            OptList.Items.Add(new ListItem("Marketing Mailings", "1"));
            OptList.Items.Add(new ListItem("3rd Party Mailings", "2"));
            OptList.Items.Add(new ListItem("VISA Promotions", "3"));
        }
```

Within my Submit_Click where the body of the email is created:

```
sb.Append("<u>Opt-Out Preference</u><br/>");

if (OptList.SelectedItem.Value == "1") sb.Append("<b>Marketing Mailings:</b>&nbsp;Yes<br />");
else sb.Append("<b>Marketing Mailings:</b>&nbsp;No<br />");

if (OptList.SelectedItem.Value == "2") sb.Append("<b>3rd Party Mailings:</b>&nbsp;Yes<br />");
else sb.Append("<b>3rd Party Mailings:</b>&nbsp;No<br />");

if (OptList.SelectedItem.Value == "3") sb.Append("<b>VISA Promotions:</b>&nbsp;Yes<br />");
else sb.Append("<b>VISA Promotions:</b>&nbsp;No<br />");
```

Comment: Where in your code are you checking and or getting all of the Items that are checked.. you need to utilize a foreach loop on the ListItems you should probably ad an Else statement to the if(!IsPostBack) if you are doing some sort of button Click to view the Checked Items once the __DoPostBack finishes it work / page rendering

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `SelectedItem` will return one item, not all of them.
You should modify your code to something like this:

```
if (OptList.Items[0].Selected) sb.Append("<b>Marketing Mailings:</b>&nbsp;Yes<br />");
else sb.Append("<b>Marketing Mailings:</b>&nbsp;No<br />");

if (OptList.Items[1].Selected) sb.Append("<b>3rd Party Mailings:</b>&nbsp;Yes<br />");
else sb.Append("<b>3rd Party Mailings:</b>&nbsp;No<br />");
```

etc...
Note that I'm checking each Item if it is selected instead of the `SelectedItem` value.

Another option is to iterate through all the items and find those which are selected:

```
var ListOfSelectedValues = OptList.Items.Cast<ListItem>().Where(x => x.Selected).Select(x => x.Value).ToList();
```

This will return a list of all **values** that were selected...

Comment: Gotcha, that makes sense! Thank you, I will mess around with this.

Comment: @kcray Also updated to help you extract the values that are selected... Good luck :)

Comment: Thanks again your first example worked fine with one modification it needs to be OptList.Items rather then OptList.Item. Thanks, saved me a ton of time on this!